# Why is `config.status --recheck` being used at all? – because it doesn't *save* anything

Tags: build, configure, autoconf, automake

I've just run `./config.status --recheck` and it didn't take into account the changes that I've made to the `configure` script – i.e.: `Makefile`s haven't been regenerated.

This puzzles me… What is the use of this script, then? It automatically detects changes on `make` so that it then re-runs `./configure` with all the options recalled and reused from the disk, but **that's all that it does** – the result of this operation **isn't saved** to the disk … What is the use of the `I've had detected some changes to the build scripts` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It automatically detects changes on `make` so that it then re-runs `./configure` with all the options recalled and reused from the disk

Which seems to be a *very good* use case.

If you fixed something in the build system, and want to rebuild, chances are you want to keep all the options passed to `configure` when you last ran it.

> the result of this operation isn't saved to the disk

This is not really true.
`./config.status --recheck` does run `configure` with the `--no-create` option, which says to "not create output files", but that's only half-true: It *does* update the `config.status` script itself.

Typically you do not run `config.status` manually, but it gets invoked automatically by `make`. And `make` will then typically also invoke the just updated `config.status` (without the `--recheck` flag), which in turn *will* update your `Makefile`.
And then it will build the project using the updated `Makefile`.